# How do I properly send a scanned variable to rsi to have it print in a loop?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to convert a c code Fibonacci sequence loop into assembly. But I'm having trouble actually printing the values properly

```
_start:
        push rbp
        mov rbp,rsp
        sub rsp, 8

        mov rdi, asknum
        push rdi
        xor rax, rax
        call printf

        mov rdi, format
        pop rdi
        push rdi
        mov rsi, var1
        push rsi
        xor rax, rax
        call scanf

        mov rdi, title  ; Title = "Fib Numbers"
        pop rdi
        push rdi        ; Title on stack, gets printed with call printf
        xor rax,rax
        call printf


        mov rcx, 10     ; Counter
        mov rax, rsi    ; Data accumulator; does the calculation for the algebra
        mov rbx, 1      ; Temporary value
```

This is my initialization. I have declared a few variables

```
section .data
        format: db "%d", 0xa, 0
        title: db "Fib Numbers", 10, 0
        asknum: db "Enter a number to get the fibonacci sequence of: ", 10, 0

section .bss
    var1 resd 1      ; Variable for scanf
```

This is the sort of output I get

```
Enter a number to get the fibonacci sequence of: 
1
4206708
1
4206709
4206710
8413419
12620129
21033548
33653677
54687225
88340902
```

What do I do to fix that?

Comment: You don't need those pushes and pops.  For example, `pop rdi` overwrites the format-string address that you just put there with `mov rdi, format`.  In x86-64 Linux/Mac, functions take their first 6 args in registers, not the stack.  Use a debugger to see what's in registers, and / or use `ltrace ./a.out` to trace the library function calls you're making.

Comment: Calling standard library functions like `printf` and `scanf` is a bad idea when you define `_start` instead of `main`. The C runtime library has initialization code that you're potentially skipping.